# Find span with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm starting to programe in Python but i have a little problem.
I want to click in this part. But when i run  the program , it results that has a problem.

[image: 1]

```
for driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//span[@class='link-indicator'][contains(text(),'View IP Detail')])
.click()
```

I write this code but my program doesn't run

Somebody can help me please.

Comment: but sorry i dont understand about delated 21 in body

Comment: Which errors did you get when trying to run the code?

Comment: @MartinGonzález _delated 21 in body_ was the code trial part which was converted as code snippet from the body.

Answer (score 2):

To click on the element with text as **View IP Detail** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and the *textContext*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='link-indicator'][contains(.,'View IP Detail')]").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath` and the *textContext* of preceding element:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'ISP')]//following::span[@class='link-indicator'][contains(.,'View IP Detail')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and the *textContext*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='link-indicator'][contains(.,'View IP Detail')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and the *textContext* of preceding element:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'ISP')]//following::span[@class='link-indicator'][contains(.,'View IP Detail')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```